# Django script - ImportError: "cannot import name widgets"

Tags: django

I'm resurrecting a script that used to work (months ago).  It's a command-line script that uses the Django ORM.  The first time I reference a Django class, I get a stack trace from deep within Django (django/contrib/admin/options.py), telling me "ImportError: cannot import name widgets"

Anyone seen anything like this before?  I don't think it's path-related, but maybe it's a circular import?  (And how could something in my code cause a circular import in the Django code?)

Comment: oh, and if I comment "django.contrib.admin" out of the INSTALLED_APPS, everything works OK.

Comment: Show your code and the stack trace, please. (Which Django version?)

Comment: strange i got the same error and it worked for me in the same way as chris . Strangely there is no stack trace !!

Comment: Hi! Help please how you solved this problem? Thanks!

Comment: I ran into this same problem. It stems from a secondary ImportError being raised in the module that Python's trying to import. To solve the problem, open a normal Python shell (not a Django shell) and try "from django.contrib.admin import widgets". In my case, this produced the error "ImportError: No module named memcache", revealing that I needed to install a memcache client.